# How to make sticky div on parent scroll

Tags: css

I try to make a div sticky when it leave the screen.

i found this example

https://codepen.io/geddski/pen/rjYpVr

```
<sidescroller>
...
</sidescroller>
```

But in my case i scroll his parent container.

My case:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzNWad

```
<div class="test">
<sidescroller>
...
</sidescroller>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make my case working?

Thank you

Comment: Please add your code as a snippet to your question.

Answer (score 0):

adding `width: 100vw;` and `position: fixed;` to your `sidescroller` will do the trick:

```
sidescroller{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: #000;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}
```

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqaYra)